# How to join general string to every first column of every sub row

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I want to join every first general string in the case below "ADMIN" and "DB" to the data which they represent and the place which will they take to be every time on the first column.

Example:

```
ADMIN
                         ADMIN_DB         Running          1          0          1          0          0          0         80
                         ADMIN_CATALOG    Running          0          0          1          0          0          0        452
                         ADMIN_CAT        Running          0          0          1          0          0          0         58
DB
               SLAVE_DB    Running          2          0          3          0          0          0         94
               DB_BAK      Running          1          0          1          0          0          0         54
             HISTORY_DB    Running          0          0          1          0          0          0         40
         HISTORY_DB_BAK    Running          0          0          1          0          0          0         59
```

Expectation:

```
ADMIN ADMIN_DB         Running          1          0          1          0          0          0         80
ADMIN ADMIN_CATALOG    Running          0          0          1          0          0          0        452
ADMIN ADMIN_CAT        Running          0          0          1          0          0          0         58
DB SLAVE_DB            Running          2          0          3          0          0          0         94
DB DB_BAK              Running          1          0          1          0          0          0         54
DB HISTORY_DB          Running          0          0          1          0          0          0         40
DB HISTORY_DB_BAK      Running          0          0          1          0          0          0         59
```

In the past I have one example this is the start point which can do the thing but I'm not aware so much in that kind of scripting: `perl -ne 'chomp; if($. % 2){print "$_,";next;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
awk 'NF==1{ val=$0; next} {print val" "$0}' input
```

You can format the output using the `column` utilty as

```
$ awk 'NF==1{ val=$0; next} { print val" "$0}' input | column -t
ADMIN  ADMIN_DB        Running  1  0  1  0  0  0  80
ADMIN  ADMIN_CATALOG   Running  0  0  1  0  0  0  452
ADMIN  ADMIN_CAT       Running  0  0  1  0  0  0  58
DB     SLAVE_DB        Running  2  0  3  0  0  0  94
DB     DB_BAK          Running  1  0  1  0  0  0  54
DB     HISTORY_DB      Running  0  0  1  0  0  0  40
DB     HISTORY_DB_BAK  Running  0  0  1  0  0  0  59
```